# How to build Outlook 2010 Add-in email dynamic context menu

Tags: ms-office, vsto, outlook-addin

Can anybody please advise how I can build a dynamic context menu for an email in Outlook 2010/2013/2016?
My task is to show list of email attachments in context menu in order to give  user an opportunity to select an attachment from the context menu and save it. Any advise or redirection to other web site tutorials are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just like ribbon buttons, the context menu must be defined in the Ribbon XML returned by your addin. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554969.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN tutorial on how to create dynamic context menu can be found in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462634(v=office.12).aspx. Although the article was written for Office 2007, the code sample works  in Outlook 2016 as well.
In order to develop dynamic context menu, the dynamicMenu control should be used. The dynamic menu content is populated in the getContent call back.